Polars successive joins alternative
I have some big dataset and I need to do multiple successive joins that are slow. I figured an alternative was to unpivot the whole  dataframe I was merging successfully, join once and then get the data where I want with a mix of pl.coalesce and pl.join (Nested polars.col()).
For my use case, this is faster than the successive joins as the baskets grow bigger but I was wondering if there was a better (faster, more memory efficient) way to achieve this.
In real life, I may perform the following operations multiple times, on more features, more symbols and bigger baskets.
import polars as pl
from polars import col
from vega_datasets import data

df = pl.from_pandas(data.stocks())
list_symbols = df.select(col('symbol').unique()).to_series().to_list()
"""
[
  "IBM",
  "MSFT",
  "AAPL",
  "AMZN",
  "GOOG"
]
"""

basket = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "MSFT": ["AMZN", "GOOG"],
        "AMZN": ["MSFT", "GOOG"],
        "GOOG": ["AAPL", "IBM"],
        "IBM": ["AMZN", "AAPL"],
        "AAPL": ["AMZN", "IBM"],
    }
).transpose(
    include_header=True,
    header_name="symbol",
    column_names=["symbol_1", "symbol_2"],
)


Successive joins

(
    df
    .join(basket, on='symbol', how='left')
    # I've put an iterative function to do the successive joins when needed, assume more than 2 joins in real life
    .join(df.select('date','symbol', col('price').name.suffix('_1')), 
          left_on = ['date', 'symbol_1'],
          right_on = ['date', 'symbol'],
          how='left',
         )
    .join(df.select('date','symbol', col('price').name.suffix('_2')), 
          left_on = ['date', 'symbol_2'],
          right_on = ['date', 'symbol'],
          how='left',
         )
)


Unpivot, join, nested col (coalesce + when)

df_pivot = (
    # I normally use the lazyframe pivot implementation to wrok with lazyframe 
    df.pivot(index='date', on='symbol', values='price')
)

(
    df.join(basket, on="symbol", how="left")
    # alternative to the successive joins
    .join(
        df_pivot.select('date', pl.exclude('date').name.suffix('_price_to_drop')),
        on="date",
        how="left",
    )
    .with_columns(
        *[
            pl.coalesce(
                pl.when(col(f'symbol_{i}')==symbol)
                .then(col(f'{symbol}_price_to_drop'))
                for symbol in list_symbols
            ).alias(f'price_{i}')
            for i in [1,2]
        ]
    )
    .select(pl.exclude("^.*to_drop$"))
)

Note that I am usually working with lazyframes. This is not the case with the example above.

The best solution to avoid multiple join operations seems to be:

put the columns that will be used for the join in a list (right_on column)
explode that list
join once on the exploded column
group_by to concat the joined results
expand the new list with a list.get iteration or a list.to_struct() .unnest

(
    df.join(basket, on="symbol", how="left")
    .with_columns(
        pl.concat_list(['symbol_1', 'symbol_2']).alias('symbol_right')
    )
    .explode('symbol_right')
    .join(df.select('date','symbol', col('price')), 
          left_on = ['date', 'symbol_right'],
          right_on = ['date', 'symbol'],
          how='left',
         )
    .group_by(['symbol', 'date'])
    .agg(
        pl.exclude('symbol_right','price_right').first(),
        col('price_right').alias('price_list_to_drop')
    )
    .with_columns(
        *[
            col("price_list_to_drop")
            .list.get(i)
            .alias(f"price_{i+1}")
            for i in [0, 1]
        ]
    )
    .select(pl.exclude("^.*to_drop$"))
)


Maybe using a list and indices to access the data can be faster than the coalesce / when.
symbol_to_idx = dict(pl.DataFrame(list_symbols, schema=['symbol']).with_row_index().select('symbol', 'index').iter_rows())
(
    df.join(basket, on="symbol", how="left")
    # alternative #2 to the successive joins 
    .join(
        df_pivot.select(
            "date", 
            pl.concat_list(list_symbols).alias("price_to_drop")
        ),
        on="date",
        how="left",
    )
    .with_columns([col(f'symbol_{i}').replace(symbol_to_idx).alias(f'symbol_index_{i}_to_drop') for i in [1,2]])
    .with_columns(*[col('price_to_drop').list.get(col(f'symbol_index_{i}_to_drop')).alias(f'price_{i}') for i in [1,2]])
    .select(pl.exclude("^.*to_drop$"))
)


Doesn't seem faster for 2 potential reasons : 1/ pl.concat_list is slow (with >100 symbols), 2/ list.get is likely slower than accessing a column with pl.col directly
